# Hiding collapsible rows on page load

Tags: html, jquery, css, html-table

I'd like to have the collapsible rows in this table load collapsed; currently, they load expanded and the toggle hides them.

**Here is the CSS:**

```
.header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24pt;
    width: 90%;
}
table { 
    width: 80%; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    margin:50px auto;
    background-color: white;
    align: center;
    margin-top:-15px;
    }

th { 
    background: #605757; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    }

td, th { 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: left; 
    font-size: 18px;
    }

.labels tr td {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.label tr td label {
    display: block;
}t-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .label tr td label {
        display: block;
    }


    [data-toggle="toggle"] {
        display: none;
    }
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>XML</th>
            <th>URL for Converter</th>
            <th>API Refresh</th>
            <th>Live</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody class="hide">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
        <tbody class="labels">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <label for="washingtonarea">Washington;</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="washingtonarea" id="washingtonarea" data-toggle="toggle">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function(){
        $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
    });
});
```

I've tried a bunch of jquery snippets, none have worked.

Comment: *"Instead of posting all of the CSS, jQuery and HTML here, it is listed in that link and easy to find."* No, please include your code and create a minimal, complete, verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve The goal of your post is to help the community, not just solve your issues. The post will outlive the code on yours and 3rd party sites, so when someone searches and finds this post 2 years from now, they need code on here to reference - not on a 3rd party site.

Comment: "*With an Adblocker enabled you can’t visit WebDesignerHut.com anymore.*" Please edit your question to include the code itself.

Comment: Link as in working jsfiddle link :) please post a jsfiddle link ;)

Comment: @Mayur if possible (and quite often is) the code should be confined to the post as a verifiable example (via Code Snippet) like **Michael Coker** has stated.

Comment: sorry guys, first post, new to this. Added the code here now.

Comment: @RJfiddle thank you for adding the code, please take it one step further and make it a _Code Snippet_ (sheet of paper icon with <> on it). Verify that the toggle functionality works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean here? I can verify that the toggle functionality does work, it just starts as expanded and collapses (then expands again).

Comment: @RJfiddle make sure that the code you have provided works as you expect. One way to do this is with a Code Snippet, in the post editor you can make a Code Snippet with the icon that is a sheet of paper with an icon of code brackets. It allows you to add your HTML, CSS, JS and turn it into a live example. Right now if I recreate your project with the code provided (and include jQuery) the toggle does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the jQuery documentation for `.toggle()`

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

> "The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown."

So, you can easily change this by hiding the content in your CSS, so it's not displayed initially. Add this to your CSS:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```